# Few questions about django project

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Firstly, I have a models set up like this:

```
class Entries(models.Model):
    COMPANY = 'Company'
    SCHOOL = 'School'

    TYPES_OF_ENTRY = (
        (COMPANY, 'Company'),
        (SCHOOL, 'School'),
    )

    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    typeOfEntry = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TYPES_OF_ENTRY, default=COMPANY)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=254,null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class PhoneNumbers(models.Model):
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entries, related_name="phoneNumbers", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phoneNumber = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Telefonas turi būti įvestas tokiu formatu: '+xxxxxxxxxxx'.")

class Emails(models.Model):
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entries, related_name="emails", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
```

Have wrote simple forms for each individual model. The main thing that bothers me is **how to make a form that could take few email and phone inputs at the same post time(with one post request)**? Second question, **is it possible to make one form with all the model fields**?

Thank you for your answers and time in advance.

Comment: By the way, could you also help me with query, that would return every entry with all his phoneNumbers and emails? I know that I need to use select_related(), but I cannot get the result I want.

Comment: Use [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). And there is no reason to **SHOUT**...